# How to make frontend application talk to backend applications without creating ingress for the backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, api-gateway, kops

I have deployed a kubernetes cluster using kops. The current cluster uses an nginx ingress controller which creates a classic load balancer in AWS. I have some backend applications that talk to the frontend application and some backend services that just talk to each other. The problem is that that the only way currently to make the frontend app talk to the backend apps is by creating an ingress for the backend apps since the frontend sends requests via the domain name since it doesn't understand the internal service names. For backends, it is fine since they can talk internally just by using the service name and their respective port. How can I achieve this without having to create ingress for backends. Is it possible to do that using an Application load balancer or do I need to have an API gateway for that? How do I achieve this architecture? Adding an architecture diagram to show what I want to achieve. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Ingress controller IS an application load balancer. Your front end does need an external endpoint. Ingress controller is the best way to have one. You could expose the service directly but that would STILL create an ELB. What are you trying to eliminate? The ELB? It's possible to deploy the ingress controller without the ELB, it's not recommended

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the need for ingresses for my backend applications.

Comment: Ingress is a good thing. They allow you to expose multiple services via a single application balancer. However if you still want to get rid of it set the backend service type to LoadBalancer that will spin up an ELB to expose just that service

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly. For example, if I have a frontend let's call it -  frontend.xyz.com , how do I make sure that this frontend talks to the backend without having to create an ingress for the backend and without having to expose the backend to the outside world as well.  If I don't create the ingress for backend say backend.xyz.com the frontend cannot talk to the backend since it does not know how to route the traffic to that backend pod without an ingress.

Comment: If the service is not exposed via an ingress or a load balancer then nothing outside the cluster can reach it

Comment: Updated my question to explain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

From your "architecture diagramm" it looks like all your applications are within the cluster. So no need for ingress. You can just use kubernetes services.

Your frontend app should be able to call the endpoints of the backend services otherwise you made something wrong in the configuration of the frontend service.

If you have no chance to change the URL which the frontend app calls for backend services, you can use for example a kubernetes service with CNAME and redirect to your internal services.

Comment: My frontend app is a react app. The image gets bundled with all the  URLs. I can change the URL which is not a problem. My problem is that I am looking for a way to map the frontend with the backend without having to go through the ingress route for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need ingress to connect backend from frontend.
assuming both backend and frontend pods are running in the same kubernetes cluster. frontend service can connect backend service using service dns

```
backend-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```